# Pass a stylesheet to a Lit-Element Web component

Tags: javascript, html, css, lit-element

Is it possible to pass a stylesheet to a web component using lit-element?

I mean in a similiar way to the one used to set up the properties of the web component.

For example, I have this web component  and I want to pass it, from the outside, a stylesheet that has to be pushed to the array returned inside "static get styles" after "SharedStyles".

```
class MyComponent extends LitElement {

  static get properties() {
    return {
      name: { type: String }
    };
  }

  static get styles () {
    return [      
      super.styles,
      SharedStyles,
      css`
       
      `
    ];
  }
}
```

If I want to set the property "name" i do:

```
<my-component .name="${"Fred"}"></my-component>
```

Is there a way to pass a stylesheet to my-component?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. But you need to export css file first.

**step 1:** create styles.js

```js
import { css } from 'lit-element';
export const styleSheet = css`
  :host{
    // global css
  }
  .cssProp1{
    // your properties
  }
  .cssProp2{
    // your properties
  }
`
```

**Step 2:** import css in to your component

```js
import { styleSheet } from styles.js;

static get styles(){
  return styleSheet;
}
```

**Step 3:** render html:

```js
render(){
  return html`
    <div class="cssProp1"></div>
    <div class="cssProp2"></div>
  `
}
```

This will do the job

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already knew how to do what you described to me. "SharedStyles" in my example is used exactly as you just described. Instead, I'd have liked to pass the style sheet as well as I pass a property because I wish a different CSS style for <my-element> depending on other parameters defined in the class where I'm going to define mine <my-element> web component.